# Gain at zero hertz

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, low-pass, frequency-measurement

I have attached the figure of my circuit. I know that as the frequency rises the gain of the circuit decreases due to low pass filtering but what if I want to measure the DC output voltage ( 0 Hz) ? According to the following equation the impedance of parallel RC circuit will give me infinity if frequency  is zero ( Image attached )

[image]

but when I see low pass filtering graph it shows that the output is at maximum at 0 Hz. I am confused now, please assist me in it.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: When frequency is zero that equation reduces to R, not infinity.

Comment: Oh hey I am really sorry, I have posted the question quickly without even noticing the equation properly ( I am such a dumb ). Yeah the gain is at highest when f = 0 Hz. I am using this circuit for determination of thermopile's time constant ( which I have connected at INA ) by measuring the output of the circuit at different optical chopper frequencies. I have noticed that when the optical chopper frequency is at zero hertz, the gain is lower than when it is at 4 Hz. What could be the reason ?

Comment: This question is quite a bit different than the original so you may want to post a new query, and perhaps elaborate what "optical chopper frequencies" refers to in your context.

Comment: this is **not** an answer to your question. This is not a discussion forum. If you have to make small adjustments to your question, **edit** it. If you are asking a **new** question (and it seems that's what happens here), ask a **new** question. You need to add signficant details to your new question, as well, because you're suddenly adding a lot of new things!

Comment: The optical chopper starts from 4 Hz hertz and goes until 40 hertz. Should I post the question again ?

Comment: Forget the equations, at DC the cap can be considered open, so you have a gain of 1001 by inspection.  As frequency increases the impedance of the cap will decrease so you'll have a single pole LPF response.

Comment: @Pukhtun Yes, seems like you should post a new question with more detail about your setup.

Comment: @Pukhtun - You have answers to this original question, so the best approach I can suggest is to upvote the helpful answers here (your votes won't show yet, due to your low rep), [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer here to effectively close *this* question, and I see that you have [already asked a new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/598997). Please make sure that new question contains *all* the points you want to ask. Please review the [tour] and [help]. Thanks.

Comment: Note the nominal gain of this circuit is 1+200k/200 = 1001. It will be slightly lower than that because the opamp's gain is 130 dB

Answer (score 2):

Your equation does not go to infinity as the frequency goes to zero. As frequency goes to zero the equation goes to \$R\$. So, you should see maximum gain at \$f=0\$.

Answer (score 2):

If you set f = 0 in your equation, the impedance is just R. And you can calculate the gain from that.

Answer (score 0):

> *According to the following equation the impedance of parallel RC
> circuit will give me infinity if frequency is zero ( Image attached )*

[image]

The formula above does not relate to your circuit at all.

The gain of your circuit at DC is 1001 because the first op-amp has a gain of: -

$$1 + \dfrac{R_{16}}{R_{15}} = 1 + 1000 = 1001$$

And, the 2nd op-amp is a unity gain buffer.