# Output voltage at different output optical chopper frequencies

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, low-pass, thermocouple

I have a circuit as shown in the figure and I am using it to extract output voltage of thermopile (to determine the time constant of thermopile ) at different output frequencies. The optical chopper is placed between thermopile with its circuit and the blackbody radiator. The thermopile is connected to the non inverting terminal of the amplifier (INA).

When the optical chopper is at 0 Hz, the output voltage should be maximum and there should be a gain of 1000 but this is not the case in my setup. The gain is lower than when the optical chopper is at 4 Hz.

What could be  the reason for such behaviour?

[image]

Comment: How are you measuring the 'gain' at 0 Hz ? Perhaps there is a DC offset in your circuit ?
What is the purpose of U1D ? VOUTA is already a buffered signal.
You do have to be careful how your grounds are connected -- R15 and Kanal A

Comment: What gain do you measure?

Comment: The gain at zero hertz is 850 and the gain at 4 Hz is 1006

Comment: As @jp314 said it's probably the offset voltage.  The AD8630 can have up to 5 uV of offset, which with a gain of 1000 can be 5mV on the output.  You don't say what the signal level is, but check your output voltage with the input grounded.  Then use that to calculate the actual gain at DC.

Comment: @Pukhtun The datasheet says it can *"achieve a high degree of precision through a patented combination of auto-zeroing and chopping."* This makes me feel a very strong need to ask for more information from Analog. You probably cannot mentally treat these exactly like you may a standard opamp. Especially when you are optically chopping, too. Also a voltage gain of 1000 is 60 dB. Then I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mckgb.png) on the datasheet. Is that maybe 50 dB there? I also don't see anything with respect to your circuit developing the signal to the input. That's all I have to add.

Comment: At zero Hz, the optical chopper may be either activating the thermopile or it may be deactivating it or, somewhere in between.